# Continuous buffer from individual polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, buffer, stream

I have a stream segment for which I am trying to find a buffer around with criteria as 5m of elevation. So for each straight line within a stream segment, I have found buffer (polygon) for it. Now I need to merge this buffers in such a way that they form a continuous single polygon i.e. without any gaps and overlaps between them. Is there any way in QGIS or any python code to achieve the same?

[image: Stream Segment with buffer]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **Processing toolbox** u have a treatment called "**buffer**" u can try

Tick then the checkbox "**dissolve result**" and u will get one buffer **only**.

*If your starting point was a line layer, the buffer(s) you're showing don't look like usual buffers (too angulous to be real buffer imho ...)*